# How do I compile my application with static library?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, static-libraries, linker-errors, physics-engine

I am currently trying to use reactphysics3d library to make simple pariticle collision simulator. https://www.reactphysics3d.com/

I tried to compile my c++ file with the static library but it doesn't compile well. The directory structure is something like this.

```
ParticleSimulation
 |
 |-- test.cpp
 |    
 |-- lib  
 |   |-- libreactphysics3d.a
 |    
 |-- reactphysics3d
 |   |-- src
 |       |-- reactphysics3d.h
```

My test code is

```
#include "reactphysics3d.h"

using namespace reactphysics3d;

int main() {
    rp3d::SphereShape * sphereShape = new SphereShape(1.0);
    delete sphereShape;
}
```

I tried to compile with

```
gcc -std=c++11 -Ireactphysics3d/src -Llib -lreactphysics3d -o myapp test.cpp ./lib/libreactphysics3d.a
```

The entire error message is too long to post here(over 30000 characters exceeds the limit of a single post of Stackoverflow). The first lines of the message are

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::__basic_string_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::str() const in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      reactphysics3d::ConcaveMeshShape::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      reactphysics3d::ConcaveMeshShape::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "std::runtime_error::runtime_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::init() in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Edge>::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Edge> const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int> const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<unsigned int, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>::operator[](reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::operator[](reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      ...
  "std::runtime_error::~runtime_error()", referenced from:
      reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::init() in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Edge>::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Edge> const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int> const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<unsigned int, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>::operator[](reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::operator[](reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string<std::nullptr_t>(char const*) in test-db2b03.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&, char const*) in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::FixedJoint::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(FixedJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Vector3::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(FixedJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Quaternion::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(FixedJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::HingeJoint::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(HingeJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Vector3::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(HingeJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Quaternion::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(HingeJoint.cpp.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::FixedJoint::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(FixedJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Vector3::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(FixedJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Quaternion::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(FixedJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::HingeJoint::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(HingeJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Vector3::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(HingeJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Quaternion::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(HingeJoint.cpp.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::insert(unsigned long, char const*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&) in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::FixedJoint::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(FixedJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Vector3::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(FixedJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Quaternion::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(FixedJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::HingeJoint::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(HingeJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Vector3::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(HingeJoint.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Quaternion::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(HingeJoint.cpp.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
```

and the last lines are

```
      non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::to_string(float)", referenced from:
      reactphysics3d::SphereShape::to_string() const in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::CapsuleShape::to_string() const in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::SliderJoint::to_string() const in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::HingeJoint::to_string() const in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::Vector3::to_string() const in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::Quaternion::to_string() const in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::Vector3::to_string() const in libreactphysics3d.a(FixedJoint.cpp.o)
      ...
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in test-db2b03.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in libreactphysics3d.a(TriangleShape.cpp.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in libreactphysics3d.a(BoxShape.cpp.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in libreactphysics3d.a(DynamicAABBTree.cpp.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in libreactphysics3d.a(mathematics_functions.cpp.o)
      ...
  "typeinfo for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "typeinfo for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "typeinfo for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      typeinfo for std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "typeinfo for std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      typeinfo for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "typeinfo for std::runtime_error", referenced from:
      reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::init() in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Edge>::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Edge> const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int> const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<unsigned int, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>::operator[](reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::operator[](reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      ...
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for reactphysics3d::DynamicAABBTreeOverlapCallback in test-db2b03.o
      typeinfo for reactphysics3d::Joint in test-db2b03.o
      typeinfo for reactphysics3d::Joint in libreactphysics3d.a(FixedJoint.cpp.o)
      typeinfo for reactphysics3d::Joint in libreactphysics3d.a(HingeJoint.cpp.o)
      typeinfo for reactphysics3d::Joint in libreactphysics3d.a(SliderJoint.cpp.o)
      typeinfo for reactphysics3d::Joint in libreactphysics3d.a(BallAndSocketJoint.cpp.o)
      typeinfo for reactphysics3d::CollisionShape in libreactphysics3d.a(CollisionShape.cpp.o)
      ...
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for reactphysics3d::ConvexShape in test-db2b03.o
      typeinfo for reactphysics3d::ConvexPolyhedronShape in test-db2b03.o
      typeinfo for reactphysics3d::BoxShape in test-db2b03.o
      typeinfo for reactphysics3d::SphereShape in test-db2b03.o
      typeinfo for reactphysics3d::CapsuleShape in test-db2b03.o
      typeinfo for reactphysics3d::TriangleShape in test-db2b03.o
      typeinfo for reactphysics3d::ConcaveShape in test-db2b03.o
      ...
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "operator delete[](void*)", referenced from:
      reactphysics3d::TriangleVertexArray::~TriangleVertexArray() in libreactphysics3d.a(TriangleVertexArray.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::TriangleVertexArray::~TriangleVertexArray() in libreactphysics3d.a(TriangleVertexArray.cpp.o)
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      _main in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::BoxShape::~BoxShape() in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::SphereShape::~SphereShape() in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::CapsuleShape::~CapsuleShape() in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::TriangleShape::~TriangleShape() in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::ConvexTriangleAABBOverlapCallback::~ConvexTriangleAABBOverlapCallback() in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::BallAndSocketJoint::~BallAndSocketJoint() in test-db2b03.o
      ...
  "operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
      reactphysics3d::TriangleVertexArray::computeVerticesNormals() in libreactphysics3d.a(TriangleVertexArray.cpp.o)
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _main in test-db2b03.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::str() const in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
  "___cxa_allocate_exception", referenced from:
      reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::init() in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Edge>::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Edge> const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int> const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<unsigned int, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>::operator[](reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::operator[](reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      ...
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in test-db2b03.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in libreactphysics3d.a(TriangleShape.cpp.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face* std::__1::uninitialized_copy<reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*>(reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*) in libreactphysics3d.a(BoxShape.cpp.o)
      ___clang_call_terminate in libreactphysics3d.a(BoxShape.cpp.o)
      ...
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveMeshShape.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face* std::__1::uninitialized_copy<reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*>(reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*) in libreactphysics3d.a(BoxShape.cpp.o)
  "___cxa_free_exception", referenced from:
      reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::init() in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Edge>::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Edge> const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int> const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<unsigned int, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>::operator[](reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::operator[](reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      ...
  "___cxa_pure_virtual", referenced from:
      vtable for reactphysics3d::ConvexShape in test-db2b03.o
      vtable for reactphysics3d::ConvexPolyhedronShape in test-db2b03.o
      vtable for reactphysics3d::ConcaveShape in test-db2b03.o
      vtable for reactphysics3d::CollisionShape in libreactphysics3d.a(CollisionShape.cpp.o)
      vtable for reactphysics3d::ConvexShape in libreactphysics3d.a(ConvexShape.cpp.o)
      vtable for reactphysics3d::ConcaveShape in libreactphysics3d.a(ConcaveShape.cpp.o)
      vtable for reactphysics3d::ConvexPolyhedronShape in libreactphysics3d.a(ConvexPolyhedronShape.cpp.o)
      ...
  "___cxa_rethrow", referenced from:
      reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face* std::__1::uninitialized_copy<reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*>(reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Face*) in libreactphysics3d.a(BoxShape.cpp.o)
  "___cxa_throw", referenced from:
      reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::init() in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Edge>::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::HalfEdgeStructure::Edge> const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int> const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<unsigned int, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::add(reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > const&, bool) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int>::operator[](reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      reactphysics3d::Map<reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::operator[](reactphysics3d::Pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&) in libreactphysics3d.a(HalfEdgeStructure.cpp.o)
      ...
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      _main in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::BoxShape::to_string() const in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::SphereShape::to_string() const in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::CapsuleShape::to_string() const in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::TriangleShape::to_string() const in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::BallAndSocketJoint::to_string() const in test-db2b03.o
      reactphysics3d::SliderJoint::to_string() const in test-db2b03.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I feel very uncomfortable with compiling c/c++ project with gcc/g++ compiler.
Could you help me to figure the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: "The error message is too messy to post here." No it's not. It is the
essential information. The message you *have* posted is merely the linker
saying "...so that didn't work", for the reasons explained in the messy
messages.

Comment: The problem is specifically that you _do_ feel uncomfortable, and you're refusing to read the error message because it looks scary. Relax, take it one line at a time, and don't worry if you don't understand all of it at first. It's all information, it just takes some time and effort to learn how to decode that information. There's no point asking for help, though, if you won't share it with _us_ because it looks messy to _you_

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I added the error message that I got to give you more information. However, since the error message is too long to post in a single post(it is more than 30000 characters which exceeds the limit), I put the first few lines and the last few lines of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your commandline:

```
gcc -std=c++11 -Ireactphysics3d/src -Llib -lreactphysics3d -o myapp test.cpp ./lib/libreactphysics3d.a
```

one of which is responsible for all the undefined reference linkage errors you have actually posted
(although possibly not responsible for other linkage errors that we cannot see).

That mistake is that you are attempting to link an application containing compiled C++ using the
GCC C frontend (`gcc`), instead of the C++ frontend (`g++`).

Compiled C++ will typically make references to symbols that are defined in the standard C++ library.
Yours does so. So your program must be linked with the standard C++ library. `g++` adds the
standard C library and the standard C++ library to the linkage automatically. `gcc` adds only
the standard C library. That is the difference between the two frontends. So your linkage
fails because references to symbols defined by the standard C++ library are not resolved. To
fix this, replace `gcc` with `g++` in your commandline.

The other mistake - although it is innocuous in this case - is that the commandline:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Ireactphysics3d/src -Llib -lreactphysics3d -o myapp test.cpp
```

would be an example of [Your linkage consumes libraries before the object files that refer to them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43305704/1362568),
which is yet another routine cause of linkage failures for undefined references.

Libraries must appear in the linkage sequence *after* the files that depend on them.

The only reason that your linkage does not exhibit additional undefined reference errors on that
score is that in your actual commandline, having placed `-lreactphysics3d` *first* in the
linkage sequence, where it has no effect, you then add the same library again to the linkage
sequence, by name - `./lib/libreactphysics3d.a` - *after* the file that depends on it, where
it *is* effective. To get rid of this redundancy, use either the more conventional:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Ireactphysics3d/src -o myapp test.cpp -Llib -lreactphysics3d
```

or the less conventional:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Ireactphysics3d/src -o myapp test.cpp ./lib/libreactphysics3d.a
```